# Create a CMS for multiple users

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress, joomla-extensions, authentication

I have a general question I just had no other way to find the answers (didnt knew even what to google.. =), I want to build a CMS for multiple users, but I want to control user registration i.e. authorize every incoming user and after wards I want the user to have ability to upload files (images to be specific), with so every user will only be able to see his content and not others (like instagram has dropped the "follow" part part and now you can only see you photos...).

as for the user authorization I know Joomla! and Wordpress have those plugins I just dont know where to look for a plugin that will make my site a picasa\instagram like...
I will appreciate any kind of help\suggestion\etc...

P.s
I looked for something relevant an hour before posting my question here..as I said there might be a really simple solution (like a plusgin for those out-of-the-box CMS systems) I just have no clue what exactly to google, also im a coder, but I guess creating a CMS like that myself (using php+mysql) will take 10 times the time plus they have considered all the security issues which I will probabley bump while coding...

Tnx in advance.. =)

Answer (score 0):

You might get more help in a wordpress or joomla related forum. This site is mainly for coding.